# Every matrix is a root of a polynomial: A combinatorial proof

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let's begin with a simple proposition:

> For every matrix $ M \in M_n(\mathbb{C}) $  there exists a non-zero polynomial $ p(x) $ such that $ p(M) = 0$.

We can show it direcly from Cayley–Hamilton theorem, but there is also a
non-constrctive combinatorial proof: Let $ M $ be such matrix, and take powers of $ M $ (including $ 0 $). Then we can take the first $ n^2+1 $-th such powers.

This set have to be linearly-dependent, becuase the vector space $ M_n(\mathbb{C}) $ is a $n^2$-dimentional space, and this gives us a polynomial $ p(x) $ such that $ p(M) = 0 $.

The problem with this prove is that we get a polynomial of degree $ n^2 $ where there is such polynomial of degree $ n $.

I tried to improve the degree of the polynomial (by analysis of $ \langle M \rangle $ ), but I didn't got nothing.

Is there any variant of such method that yeilds a polynomial of degree $ o(n^2) $?

Comment: What is $A?$ Do you mean non-zero polynomial?

Comment: @gammatester Yes, the polynomial need to be non zero. $ A $ is $ M $ (I'll edit it). Thanks

Comment: For many concrete examples of $M$, you will probably be able to prove by direct computation that the space of matrices commuting with $M$ has dimension $n$ (since for example, this is true for any matrix with $n$ distinct eigenvalues).  Then, each power of $M$ lives in this restricted space.

Comment: @DanielSchepler You actually don't need distinct eigenvalues - if the eigenvectors span the whole space, $KMK^{-1} = diag$ for some diagonal matrix. The space of diagonal matrices is of dimension $n$. Now write the corresponding lin. dependence equation and you're done. But what about non-distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: @pepa.dvorak $I_n$ is diagonalizable but its centralizer is the whole $n^2$-dimensional space.  So, the argument doesn't work for every $M$ (hence why I didn't post it as an answer).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Your idea is interesting (it relates to the definition of regular element of a lie algebra), but as you pointed out it doesn't cover all the matrices. I think pepa.dvorak intended talked about the general proposition (as I understand, he meant that if the matrix is diagonalizable the the power s[ace of $ M $ is a conjugacy class of the diagonal matrices. To reduce some techical problem with such ideas I will replace $ \mathbb{R} $ by $ \mathbb{C} $. Thanks
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_element_of_a_Lie_algebra